# Cannot add to my List, throws a NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

What im trying to do, I think, is fairly simple, but then I come from a PHP Background (you know, where most of the heavy lifting is done with and for you).

basically, heres my log:

```
12-06 15:45:18.282: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Matching Providers are: [network, gps]
12-06 15:45:18.282: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Um, whats the best provder? Well its obviously 'network'
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:49, Long: -116
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:50, Long: -116
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:49, Long: -117
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:49, Long: -115
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:49, Long: -117
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.753: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:49, Long: -117
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:50, Long: -115
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:49, Long: -116
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:50, Long: -118
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.763: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Location Data: Lat:49, Long: -114
12-06 15:45:18.783: D/MAPVIEW(32047): Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: java.lang.NullPointerException
12-06 15:45:18.783: D/AndroidRuntime(32047): Shutting down VM
12-06 15:45:18.783: W/dalvikvm(32047): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d5a0)
```

You will see that I'm trying to add to a list of coordinates, and the try catch is catching the exception. 
( Don't worry about the crash for now tho! I'll get to that. )

So without much further adeu, heres my relevant code:

```
package com.private.clientndablocked;

// ... imports

public class ShowMapView extends MapActivity {

    // ... some initializers
    List<int[]> allLocations;


    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // .. whole bunch of other unreleated stuff



        // A single json object, this gets populated with cherry picked json array items
        JSONObject obj = null;

        // go through each of the items in the json array
        for(int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {

            try {
                // We must try to get the object first
                obj = (JSONObject) json.get(i);
            } catch (JSONException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Initialize temp data with defaults
            int Latitude = 0;
            int Longitude = 0;
            String Title = "";
            String ID = "";
            int[] coords = new int[2];

            // So we actually have a picked item?
            if(obj != null)
                try {

                    // Lets try to assign the temp vars with their real data
                    Latitude = (int) (obj.getDouble("lat") * 1e6);
                    Longitude = (int) (obj.getDouble("long") * 1e6);
                    Title = (String) (obj.getString("title"));
                    ID = (String) (obj.getString("id"));


                    // Save the lat and long of the new location data (non micro) 
                    // This stuff goes into allLocations List
                    coords[0] = obj.getInt("lat");
                    coords[1] = obj.getInt("long");

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            // Create a new GeoPoint to store the microdegrees into
            GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(
                Latitude, 
                Longitude
            );

            // Create a new OverlayItem with the GeoPoint and a title and snippet
            OverlayItem overlayitem = new OverlayItem(
                point, 
                Title, 
                ID
            );

            itemizedoverlay.addOverlay(overlayitem);
            mapOverlays.add(itemizedoverlay);

            Log.d("MAPVIEW", "Location Data: Lat:" + coords[0] + ", Long: " + coords[1] );

            try{
                allLocations.add(coords); // ************* this is whats failing ******************
            } catch(Exception e) {
                Log.d("MAPVIEW", "Could not add coordinate array to List, Error: " + e.toString());
            }



        }

        // ... whole bunch more unrelated stuff


}
```

Now the only thing that gets a little different is when i add

```
allLocations = Arrays.asList();
```

above the big for loop json extractor. This then makes the program throw UnsupportedOperationException.

So honestly, i'm not sure what else to do. ..

I thought I had Lists figured out, but evidently I do not :(

(ps: I want to store these like this so i can do this:

```
int minLat = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxLat = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int minLon = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
int maxLon = Integer.MIN_VALUE;

for (int[] l : allLocations) { 

    int lat = (int) l[0];
    int lon = (int) l[1];


    maxLat = Math.max(lat, maxLat);
    minLat = Math.min(lat, minLat);
    maxLon = Math.max(lon, maxLon);
    minLon = Math.min(lon, minLon);

 }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not see where you have initialized your list. You must intialize your list to use it first

```
allLocations = new ArrayList<int[]>();
```

Also, I am not sure how are you using

```
Arrays.asList
```

without getting a compilation exception. The method takes an argument of array. Check out the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList%28T...%29):

Comment: AH!! There we go! See i attempted to do that, but being fairly new I must have messed up syntax somewhere because Eclipse.. created this whole class override method when i typed in the final ) character, and it still error-ed out so i figured I went down the wrong path :( 
Thanks for the ultra quick response!

Comment: Thank goodness for this. I just spent an hour casting and doing other non-essential stuff. Php makes things so easy, but i must admit, java is turning out to be sweet.